# Why doesn't "timedatectl list-timezones" list ALL timezones?

Tags: linux, systemd, timezone

Why does timezonectl not list all timezones available?

```
$ timedatectl
  ⋮
  Timezone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
  ⋮

$ timedatectl list-timezones | grep -i utc
  -no output-

$ timedatectl list-timezones | wc -l
  417
```

`ls /usr/share/zoneinfo` includes UTC, UCT, GMT, Universal, etc. But none of those are included in the list either.

I notice this in CentOS 7, specifically, and have had identical results on two different machines. Interestingly enough, however, Ubuntu shows "UTC" but not "GMT". Which does exist in ./zoneinfo. So the whole thing is quite confusing to me.

Comment: Confirmed this doesn't appear on C7, though on my Fedora 22 system I see 418 entries, the last one being UTC.

Comment: found out via strace that timedatectl uses `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab`. I guess your question has been answered in [this Unix Exchange question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35781/why-is-zone-tab-missing-so-many-time-zones)